# error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol dbbind referenced in function

Tags: c++, postgresql, visual-studio, linker, tds-fdw

I'm trying to compile [`tds_fdw`](https://github.com/tds-fdw/tds_fdw) for Windows 64bit using Visual Studio Community 2017, but I'm getting the errors below.

The C/C++ Additional Include Directories are:

```
E:\Downloads\FreeTDS-1.00-x86\freetds-1.00\include
C:\Apps\postgres\pgsql-10.0\include\server\port\win32_msvc
C:\Apps\postgres\pgsql-10.0\include\server\port\win32
C:\Apps\postgres\pgsql-10.0\include
C:\Apps\postgres\pgsql-10.0\include\server
E:\Workspace\git\tds_fdw\include
%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)
```

The Linker Input has Additional Dependencies:

```
C:\Apps\postgres\pgsql-10.0\lib\postgres.lib
```

What am I missing?

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: tds_fdw, Configuration: Release x64 ------
1>deparse.c
1>options.c
1>tds_fdw.c
1>Generating Code...
1>   Creating library E:\Workspace\git\tds_fdw\x64\Release\tds_fdw.lib and object E:\Workspace\git\tds_fdw\x64\Release\tds_fdw.exp
1>tds_fdw.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol dbbind referenced in function tdsGetRowCountShowPlanAll
1>tds_fdw.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol dbclose referenced in function estimate_path_cost_size
1>tds_fdw.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol dbcmd referenced in function tdsExecuteQuery
1>tds_fdw.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol dbcolname referenced in function tdsGetColumnMetadata
1>tds_fdw.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol dbcoltype referenced in function tdsGetColumnMetadata
1>tds_fdw.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol dbconvert referenced in function tdsConvertToCString
1>tds_fdw.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol dbiscount referenced in function tdsGetRowCountExecute
1>tds_fdw.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol dbcount referenced in function tdsGetRowCountExecute
1>tds_fdw.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol dbdata referenced in function tdsIterateForeignScan
1>tds_fdw.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol dbdatecrack referenced in function tdsDatetimeToDatum
1>tds_fdw.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol dbdatlen referenced in function tdsIterateForeignScan
1>tds_fdw.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol dberrhandle referenced in function estimate_path_cost_size
1>tds_fdw.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol dbexit referenced in function estimate_path_cost_size
1>tds_fdw.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol dbinit referenced in function estimate_path_cost_size
1>tds_fdw.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol dblogin referenced in function estimate_path_cost_size
1>tds_fdw.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol dbloginfree referenced in function estimate_path_cost_size
1>tds_fdw.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol dbmsghandle referenced in function estimate_path_cost_size
1>tds_fdw.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol dbnextrow referenced in function tdsGetRowCountExecute
1>tds_fdw.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol dbnumcols referenced in function tdsGetRowCountShowPlanAll
1>tds_fdw.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol tdsdbopen referenced in function tdsSetupConnection
1>tds_fdw.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol dbresults referenced in function tdsExecuteQuery
1>tds_fdw.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol dbsqlexec referenced in function tdsExecuteQuery
1>tds_fdw.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol dbuse referenced in function tdsSetupConnection
1>tds_fdw.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol dbwillconvert referenced in function tdsConvertToCString
1>tds_fdw.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol dbsetlname referenced in function tdsSetupConnection
1>tds_fdw.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol dbsetlversion referenced in function tdsSetupConnection
1>E:\Workspace\git\tds_fdw\x64\Release\tds_fdw.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 26 unresolved externals
1>Done building project "tds_fdw.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

## Update: files from FreeTDS

```
freetds-1.00\bin
freetds-1.00\etc
freetds-1.00\include
freetds-1.00\lib
freetds-1.00\README.tests
freetds-1.00\sbin
freetds-1.00\var
freetds-1.00\bin\bsqldb.exe
freetds-1.00\bin\bsqlodbc.exe
freetds-1.00\bin\datacopy.exe
freetds-1.00\bin\defncopy.exe
freetds-1.00\bin\freebcp.exe
freetds-1.00\bin\osql
freetds-1.00\bin\sqsh.exe
freetds-1.00\bin\tsql.exe
freetds-1.00\etc\freetds.conf
freetds-1.00\etc\locales.conf
freetds-1.00\etc\pool.conf
freetds-1.00\include\bkpublic.h
freetds-1.00\include\cspublic.h
freetds-1.00\include\cstypes.h
freetds-1.00\include\ctpublic.h
freetds-1.00\include\odbcss.h
freetds-1.00\include\sqldb.h
freetds-1.00\include\sqlfront.h
freetds-1.00\include\sybdb.h
freetds-1.00\include\syberror.h
freetds-1.00\include\sybfront.h
freetds-1.00\include\tds_sysdep_public.h
freetds-1.00\lib\libct.a
freetds-1.00\lib\libct.la
freetds-1.00\lib\libsybdb.a
freetds-1.00\lib\libsybdb.la
freetds-1.00\lib\libtdsodbc.a
freetds-1.00\lib\libtdsodbc.la
freetds-1.00\lib\pkgconfig
freetds-1.00\lib\pkgconfig\freetds.pc
freetds-1.00\sbin\tdspool.exe
freetds-1.00\sbin\tdssrv.exe
freetds-1.00\var\log
```

Comment: @craig-ringer - my starting point was your excellent blog post at https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/compiling-postgresql-extensions-visual-studio-windows/ - can you please help?

Answer (score 1):

You failed to link to the FreeTDS `.lib`. You'll also need to ensure the associated `.dll` is in your `PATH` or copied to the same directory as the extension you built.

Comment: Thanks, Craig, I was trying to do something like that, but I don't see any `.dll` or `.lib` files in the Windows distribution of FreeTDS - https://sourceforge.net/projects/freetdswindows/ - any ideas?  I will add the list of files I got from FreeTDS to my question above.

Comment: Presumably you have to compile FreeTDS then, or get a binary distribution that's pre-compiled